# Google API: Quota Limit Reset Times and Timezone

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, rate-limiting

Does anyone have any information on the times in which the quota limits/rate limits reset for the following Google APIs? Most of the APIs above have daily quotas mentioning that the quotas reset the next day - in which I would like to know the time and timezone, if anyone has the information.

- Google Places Details
- Google Places Search
- Google Places Text Search
- Google News Search
- Google Analytics Profiles
- Google Analytics Data
- Google Custom Search
- Google+ Search
- Google+ Activities
- Google+ Profile
- YouTube

I have done some research and some, not all, APIs do publish such information: the Google Maps API for work mentions that the daily quota resets at midnight, Pacific time, source: [Google Maps API for Work](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits)
Also, in the Merchant Circle API, it publishes the reset time as 12AM, PST, source: [Merchant Circle API](http://api.merchantcircle.com/api/v1/docs)

Comment: To my knowledge they all reset at midnight PST.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as possibly off-topic because its about Google Quota reset and not really about programing.

Comment: Do you have a source for why you mentioned that it resets at midnight PST?

Also, where could I ask this question aside from stackoverflow? I have seen questions regarding API quotas and limitations throughout here on StackOverflow.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Source would be my top secret contacts on the Google development teams :)

Answer (score 17):

Check the quota page in google developer console most of them say when it resets

**Daily quota resets at midnight Pacific Time (PT).**

[image]